# What is the semiperimeter of the ABCDE pentagon?

Tags: geometry

For reference: (answer $3R+r_1+r_2$)

[image]

My progress:
I think it can be solved by the property below together with the poncelet theorem and algebraic manipulation of tangents but I couldn't..

[image]

[image]

Comment: What role plays the second figure with respect to the question asked ?

Comment: @JeanMarie..I thought that maybe Poncelet's theorem as it involves the radius of the inscribed circle and the sides could provide some relationship for the tip triangles.

Comment: @JeanMarie See that fellow MyMolecules used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, $s$ is the sub-perimeter.

As the circle with radius $R$ is the ex-circle of $\triangle ABG$ and $\triangle EDL$ and circles with $r_1$ and $r_2$ are incircles, we have

$HE=ES=r_2 , AQ=AH=r_1$

Therefore,

$2s=(BF+FD+BA+AE+ED)\\
2s=(2R+2R+(R+r_1)+(r_1+r_2)+(R+r_2))\\
2s=(6R+2r_1+2r_2)\\
\boxed{s=3R+r_1+r_2}$
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**Hints :**

- Perimeter of pentagon = Perimeter of square $AHNE$ $-$ $(FN+NG-FG)$
- $FN+NG-FG=2\times$ inradius of $\triangle FNG$

which is similar to other three right triangles in picture and hence, its inradius is easily found.

> $$8R - 2R\times \frac{FG}{BC}$$
>  $$=8R - 2R \left( 1 - \frac{r_1}{R} - \frac{r_2}{R} \right)$$

Comment: [+1] Splendid proof

Comment: Grateful for the help but can explain $2R\times \frac{FG}{BC} \rightarrow =2R \left( 1 - \frac{r_1}{R} - \frac{r_2}{R} \right)$

Comment: @petaarantes $\frac{FG}{BC}=\frac{BC}{BC}-\frac{BF}{BC}-\frac{CG}{BC}=1-\frac{r_1}{R}-\frac{r_2}{R}$ by similarity.

Comment: Is it any specific property you are using?